# .razor.g.cs could not be found

Tags: visual-studio, blazor

I am posting a hint how to overcome issue `.razor.g.cs could not be found`.

The fix is quite simple: *shortening*  path to `MyComponent.razor` to make sure that complete path to `MyComponent.razor.g.cs` is shorter than 255.

I have experienced this issue with Source file `c:\......\very long path\obj\Debug\net5.0\RazorDeclaration\Pages\MyComponent.razor.g.cs could not be found` and complete path was 262 chars, so I just renamed component for example to 'Short.razor' and the error is gone.

Answer (score 3):

The fix is: *shortening*  path to `MyComponent.razor` to make sure that complete path to `MyComponent.razor.g.cs` is shorter than 255.

Comment: How is still still an issue on Windows 11 in VS2022? SMH.

Comment: It depends on used filesystem. Eg. FAT32 has such issues.

Comment: I'm using NTFS, I'm still running into this. It's just absurd that despite there being Windows APIs that support longer file names since forever, Microsoft Visual Studio and related tooling still has this problem in 2022.